# play crud:ov --template

Tags: windows, playframework, crud

I'm trying to overwrite the default template for a view generated by the crud module, I've been following this [tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/guide7) but when I run this command:

```
$ play crud:ov --template Posts/show
```

play! returns ***Invalid command: crud:ov***

I'm using windows command prompt, and play! framework 1.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this command :

```
$ play crud:ov {PATH_OF_YOUR_PROJECT} --template Posts/show
```

Answer (score 1):

From the online docs, it says

> Open a shell, go the application directory and type:

```
play crud:ov --template Posts/show
```

So, I think the problem is just where you are running the command from. If you are not in your application, Play does not know which application it is updating the CRUD view.

Comment: I'm definitely in the application directory, it seems to have an issue with the command crud:ov, play! keeps returning **Invalid command: crud:ov**. It's not that it doesn't know which application to work with but that it does not recognise the command crud:ov.